# Making a jQuery event trigger with both keyboard and mouse inputs inside a select element

Tags: jquery, html

OK here goes,

I am trying to write a script that, when a user keys or clicks onto an `<option id='blselect'>` within a `<select>` element an event is triggered that shows a hidden element. If any of the other `<option class='unselect'>` are clicked then the aforementioned element will be hidden.

I have gotten the script to work perfectly in regards to user clicks but the problem is if the user was to user the keyboard to work through the form.

The event wanting to be triggered for the `<option id='blselect'>` to show is as such;

```
$("#blselect").click(function() {
    $("#hidden").animate({
        opacity: 'show',
        width: "100%"
    }, 1500);
});
```

The event wanting to be triggered for the  to hide is as such;

```
$(".unselect").click(function() {
    $("#hidden").animate({
        opacity: 'hide'
    }, 1500);
});
```

That shows a CSS hidden element and of course animates the visual.

So in short, a solution that covers both keyboard and mouse inputs when a user either focuses onto the `<option id='blselect'>` or the `<option class='unselect'>` elements.

```
<li>
    <select>
        <option class="unselect" selected>Please choose an option..</option>
        <option id="blselect">John</option>
        <option class="unselect">Mike</option>
        <option class="unselect">Barry</option>
        <option class="unselect">Sally</option>
        <option class="unselect">Gertrude</option>
        <option class="unselect">Jill</option>
    </select>
</li>

<li id="hidden">
    <input type="text">
</li>

$("#blselect").click(function() {
    $("#hidden").animate({
        opacity: 'show',
        width: "100%"
    }, 1500);
});

$(".unselect").click(function() {
    $("#hidden").animate({
        opacity: 'hide'
    }, 1500);
});
```

Hope this is enough information to get people started? please let me know if you need more.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Marnix suggested, the `.change()` event is **the** correct even to use here. Otherwise you might be handling mouse or keyboard events which didn't actually change the value in the dropdown.

You probably want to add an ID to the `<select>`, in which case the code would look like:

```
var $hidden = $('#hidden');

$('#my-select-id').change(function ()
{
    var $option = $(this.options[this.selectedIndex]);
    if ($option.is('#blselect'))
    {
        $hidden.fadeIn(1500);
    }
    else if ($option.is('.unselect'))
    {
        $hidden.fadeOut(1500);
    }
});
```

Comment: perfect solution Mr Ball :) I hope I'm not being too brass and asking if it is at all possible for the .change event to handle key presses as the change and not a keypress followed and the enter/return key?

Comment: Not too brass, but not possible. The change event fires when the `<select>` _changes_, and that doesn't happen with keyboard navigation until the enter key is pressed. It makes sense for it to be that way, though.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at the [`.change()`](http://api.jquery.com/change/) event. This way, every change in a `<select>` tag is registered. Look at the examples on the [jQuery page](http://api.jquery.com/change/) to see how it works.

Comment: Yeah, I had a look at the .change event but replacing that for the .click event didn't work, I'm now guessing the way in which you would write a .change function differs to the .click way?

Comment: It should be noted that IE does _not_ fire the change event until a `blur()` event occurs. The fix is to do something like this: `$('select').click(function(){this.focus();this.blur();});`

Comment: @sholsinger, also for `<select>`? From jQuery: `For select boxes, checkboxes, and radio buttons, the event is fired immediately.` Do you have a reference for me about that?

Comment: You're right it does not affect `<select>` elements the same way. However in IE & Opera [`change()` is fired _every_ time you use the keyboard to change the value](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/events/change.html) whereas you might expect that to only fire when you **confirm** the change with the tab or enter keys. (_As it is with FF, Chrome, and Safari_)

Comment: That said, you _can_ use the `click()` event handler for `<option>` elements if you want to target them instead of the `<select>`

Answer (score 2):

You could use [`.focus()`](http://api.jquery.com/focus/) and then [`.blur()`](http://api.jquery.com/blur/)

```
function animateVisualIn(){
  $("#hidden").animate({
    opacity: 'show',
    width: "100%"
  }, 1500);
}
function animateVisualOut(){
  $("#hidden").animate({
    opacity: 'hide'
  }, 1500);
}
$('#blselect, .unselect').focus(animateVisualIn).blur(animateVisualOut);
```

I may have missed the mark on this one. But I think my example shows a good practice that you should get in the habit of using. Define the functions so they are reusable within your code. Then just pass the function name into the jQuery method that accepts a function as the argument. This allows re-use of your functions and prevents memory leakage due to passing around and re-defining anonymous functions.

Comment: Only problem I have found when trying the .focus event is that with the element in question being a <select> the .focus only triggers when you call that as the selector and wont work when calling one of its child elements. so I would have to change the #blselect to select and then the script works even when you try clicking on the <select> element.

Comment: Very good points in your edited comments, I shall do this for the future.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the .keyup(handler) jQuery method to execute a handler as well.

```
function show() {

}

function hide() {

}

$("#blselect").click(hide);
$("#blselect").keyup(hide);
```

Comment: Just tried your example, sadly the .keyup event will not work for the <select> element, any other ideas?